# Why docker container have two ip address

Tags: docker

After this command:
`lsof -i:8083`
I have this output:

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 16772 root    3u  IPv6 272754493      0t0  TCP kiwi:8083->172.17.0.4:56924 (FIN_WAIT2)
docker-pr 16772 root    4u  IPv6 272752049      0t0  TCP *:8083 (LISTEN)
```

kiwi is my Ubuntu's name. I want to know why this container has kiwi:8083 ip address while another container's output is:

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 24595 root    4u  IPv6 44055562      0t0  TCP *:8089 (LISTEN)
```

And I cannot access the first application from foreign network:8083. I want to know why it happens, what is the meaning of the first line and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: what was the exact `docker run` command did used in order to create these containers?

Comment: @root `docker run -d -it -p 8083:8080 --privileged -v /home/ivan/appetizer/demo/data:/var/atlassian/application-data/demo -v /home/ivan/appetizer/demo/localtime:/etc/localtime --name demo demoImage`

Comment: `network@8083`   do you mean -> `network:8083`?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your correction. Now I find it may be produced due to closing connection by the server.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Your container only has 1 IP address: `172.17.0.4`. The `kiwi:8083` line means something on the host is talking to the container via port 8083.

This bit:

```
*:8083 (LISTEN)
```

is telling you that the `docker-proxy` [process](https://windsock.io/the-docker-proxy/) is listening on port 8083 to connections from any network interface.

This thing:

```
kiwi:8083->172.17.0.4:56924 (FIN_WAIT2)
```

is telling you that the `docker-proxy` process on your ubuntu host is also connected via a network interface which is bound to an IP address which resolves as the hostname `kiwi`. You can check the IP address using the command

```
nslookup kiwi
```

which will return an IP address, and you can resolve the IP address to the network interface by examining the output of the following command:

```
ifconfig
```

`docker-proxy` is using the local port 8083 while connected to the server `172.17.0.4` on the remote port 56924. `172.17.0.4` would be the IP address which docker assigned to one of your containers when it attached it to docker's network bridge interface (also available in the output of `ifconfig`).

`FIN_WAIT2` means the client (`docker-proxy`) closed the connection and is [waiting for the container to close its end](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajmi). The link says:

> Some clients have faulty TCP implementations, and leave the server hanging in FIN_WAIT_2 state.

So you might be hitting some TCP bug.